# __connect_no_cancel blocks and server gets data out of order

Tags: linux, sockets, select, connect, listen

I have a TCP server using `select` to get data from a client through TCP socket.
The Server is slow in consuming data while the client is much faster. My client sends 8 bytes of data and each time it 
-open a new connection
-write data
-disconnect
Because of this ( the server socket must  accept many connection ) I increased the backlock value of `listen` to 500.

Despite this setting, at some point I can see that 
-my client blocks in a `pthread` function called `__connect_nocancel` and this happens many times.
-after a while my server starts receiving data out of orders. The first data messed up is the one where the client blocks ( followed by other ).

I thought that increasing the backlog may fix this but this issue but this is not the case.

Can You help me? I am in Linux 2.6.32

Cheers

AFG

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The backlog parameter of [`listen(2)`](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/listen.2.html) is usually capped to some value inside the OS network stack. On Linux the default is 128.

The real problem though is, as @EJP is saying, you are totally mis-using TCP.

Comment: At the end I found that if you watn bigger backlog value you need to write the value you want in /proc/sys/net/core/somaxconn

Answer (score 0):

If ordering is important, your client must just keep a single connection open and write everything via that single connection. There are no two ways about this. TCP guarantees byte ordering withing the stream. *Nothing* guarantees the ordering of server-side processing of distinct connections.

It's also considerably more efficient. At present you are exchanging about eight packets for every eight bytes, which implies an overhead of up to 160 bytes.

Comment: I know and I am aware of that; unfortunately due to circumstances (i.e. tight time to implement it ) I cannot change the project I am working on and I have to fix what I have now.